# Microsoft Virtual Assistant - The bot's Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password is incorrect

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

We are migrating our previous **MS Enterprise Bot** applications (deprecated) to the new **MS Virtual Assistant**. The default template runs well on local with the Bot Emulator v4, but when i test it on *Web Chat* or in *Microsoft Teams*, we get an Unauthorized response.

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
>   Unauthorized

Using the deployed bot URL (https://your-proj-name.azurewebsites.net/api/messages) on the Bot Emulator, we get.

> The bot's Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password is incorrect

I am lost in which because i am sure that i have the correct *MS App Id* and *MS App Password*, as we have been using it on our current Enterprise Bot deployments.

Is anyone having the same issue? Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Are MSA ID and MSA Password present on your Configuration tab on Web App Bot on Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes it is, its what i used on the MVA appsettings

Comment: Viewing it on Azure's online code editor, the appsettings MSA ID and MSA Password are both correct

Comment: Are you using a bot file or appsettings.json?

Comment: the MS Virtual Assistant does not use .bot file, its all based on configuration

Comment: I ask because the Enterprise bot DID use a bot file, so part of migration would be to change that as well, (though it is possible to still run a bot with a .bot file, just not recommended)

Comment: agree, i'll try deploying it using enterprise bot deployment steps. hopefully it will still work (as a workaround until MS sorts out MVA deployment issues)

Comment: I have some steps here on deploying the VA bots/Enterprise bots: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the latest ~/Deployment/Scripts (all files there) from the MS Virtual Assistant github repository. There were few recent updates there, and after doing so, tried the deployment using the latest patches, and everything worked fine.

I am not sure what part on the deployment script was failing, but using the recent fixes and updates did fix the issue I am encountering.

Hope this helps anyone who come across this issue.

**Pre-requisites for deployment:**

- Go to https://www.luis.ai and create an app (skip if you already have one)
- Copy your LUIS authoring key
- Copy your LUIS location
- Go to https://passwordsgenerator.net and generate a password, copy it
- Do not create an Azure Resource Group, let the deployment do this for you

**Steps for deployment (for initial deployment):**

- Empty out the values of each key for *appsettings.json* and *cognitivemodels.json*
- Clean and rebuild the MS Virtual Assistant template project
- Open (as administrator) your updated powershell (powershell core is required), and go to your project's location
- On your powershell, run this command **`az login`**, enter your credentials and close the browser afterwards, a confirmation should display after then
- On your powershell, run this command **`.\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1`**, and enter the values for each parameter. Make sure you use the copied values from above for the specified parameters asked
- Wait until the deployment completes

**Steps for updating existing deployment:**

- Clean and rebuild the MS Virtual Assistant template project
- Open (as administrator) your updated powershell (powershell core is required), and go to your project's location
- On your powershell, run this command **`az login`**, enter your credentials and close the browser afterwards, a confirmation should display after then
- On your powershell, run this command **`.\Deployment\Scripts\publish.ps1 -name YOUR_PROJECT_NAME -resourceGroup YOUR_PROJECT_RESOURCE_GROUP`**

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of the problem.
As shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLql2.png), the script prints out the following error message shortly after entering the passphrase.

```
'us@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

And if you look at the passphrase I entered

> K7=6HMCwE4&us@

you can already guess what has happened here.

Some characters in the passphrases seem to cause problems.
So far I have identified '&' and '@' as problematic characters.
Since the script finishes without any further error messages and everything else seems to work fine, it is not that obvious.